# Swift: Gesturing doesn't bring back the TabBar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, gesture

I am trying to move back from a ViewController (simple text page) to a main ViewController with a TabBar at the bottom using gesturing.

The gesture works as I return to the original main screen but there is no TabBar.

In the simple ViewController I use this code to go back to the originating ViewController.

```
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewControllerID")
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewControllerID") as? AboutViewController
            {
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewController with the TabBarController I have tried the following lines to rejuvinate the TabBarController but without any joy.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
     NSLog("TabBar true")
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to go-back don't use present as it will add the same VCS twice in the stack , you have to use unwindSegue/dismiss , or load the tabBar itself with id

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {

     // use this if it's not directly behind the dismissed VC
     let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarID") as! UITabBarController
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tab

}
```

//
[image]

Comment: In isolation I don't see where this code is meant to go. 
I was hoping to do this programatically rather than use a segue.

Comment: put it inside the action where you want to dismiss the current VC and go back to the tanBar

Comment: I suspect you're too good a programmer and going a little fast for me. The TabBar doesn't have an identifier, the VC does. If I use a line like this it almost works then gives a Thread 1: signal SIGBART error. 

let tab = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewControllerID") as! UITabBarController

Comment: AH, that one - many thanks, I should be able to sort this out now.